# Open a new Form from another Form whith ALL componentns

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

Im trying to open a new form on a click on the main form. 
The problem is the the new form oppens up but whithout any component, just embty form 
this is what i wrote.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form rr = new Form();
        this.Hide();
        rr.ShowDialog();

    }
```

Comment: you used a default `Form` which is of course empty, if you have some form template elsewhere, just use that form instead.

Comment: You'd like microsoft to ship `Form` with some controls as children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're opening basic *Form* but not **your** form (that is with controls).

Suppose your form class (which you've designed) is `MyForm`, so you should put it like

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MyForm rr = new MyForm(); // <- MyForm not Form!
    rr.ShowDialog();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** it is because you are just creating and displaying the new `Form` without adding `controls` on it.

**Method 1 :** You can Add controls to the Form created at runtime.

Try This: Adding `Label` on `Form` -similarly you can add other controls.

```
        Form rr = new Form();
        Label l1=new Label();
        l1.Text = "label 1";
        rr.Controls.Add(l1);
        this.Hide();
        rr.ShowDialog();
```

**Method 2 :**  you can create the `NewForm` from `IDE` and add then add `controls` from `DesignView`.

Adding Form from `Visual Studio` IDE:

**1.** Right click on `project`
**2.** Select `Add` -> `Windows Form...`
**3.** Now Enter form your formname  -> `SampleForm`
**4.** Now Add the `controls` on the newly created `SampleForm`
**5.** Display the newly created Form

```
SampleForm sample=new SampleForm();
sample.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a little helper function witch is this:

```
  private void ShowForm<T>() where T: Form, new ()
    {
        this.Hide();
        T form = new T();
        form.FormClosed += (s, e) => this.Show();
        form.Show();
    }
```

this is the main form witch works like a storyboard and for example when some one click a button and  im going to display a new form i do  this:

```
    private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowForm<PublishersForm>();
    }
```